Xero Accounting API 2.0 Not returning line item info
I'm using the Xero API to retrieve overpayment details with the endpoint /2.0/Overpayments. My request includes where=Contact.ContactID==Guid("a1552f33-a4c1-42e1-a8ac-226fa83a493b") AND Status=="AUTHORISED"&order=Date ASC&page=1. The API returns overpayment data, but the LineItems array is always empty, even though the overpayments have line items in Xero.
I'm using make.com to make this request*
Here's the response I get:
[
    {
        "body": {
            "Id": "e21ff760-1801-4ebc-951d-89b54db5ac58",
            "Status": "OK",
            "ProviderName": "Make",
            "DateTimeUTC": "/Date(1716450562028)/",
            "Overpayments": [
                {
                    "OverpaymentID": "8ed8b7ba-f5a3-4c90-a029-cd05e559fb7b",
                    "Type": "RECEIVE-OVERPAYMENT",
                    "RemainingCredit": 20,
                    "Allocations": [],
                    "Payments": [],
                    "HasAttachments": false,
                    "Contact": {
                        "ContactID": "a1552f33-a4c1-42e1-a8ac-226fa83a493b",
                        "Name": "Eftichios-Luke Botonakis",
                        "Addresses": [],
                        "Phones": [],
                        "ContactGroups": [],
                        "ContactPersons": [],
                        "HasValidationErrors": false
                    },
                    "DateString": "2024-05-23T00:00:00",
                    "Date": "/Date(1716422400000+0000)/",
                    "Status": "AUTHORISED",
                    "LineAmountTypes": "NoTax",
                    "LineItems": [],
                    "SubTotal": 20,
                    "TotalTax": 0,
                    "Total": 20,
                    "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1716450096677+0000)/",
                    "CurrencyCode": "EUR"
                }
            ]
        },
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "content-length": "1026",
            "server": "nginx",
            "xero-correlation-id": "e21ff760-1801-4ebc-951d-89b54db5ac58",
            "x-appminlimit-remaining": "9912",
            "x-minlimit-remaining": "59",
            "x-daylimit-remaining": "4971",
            "expires": "Thu, 23 May 2024 07:49:22 GMT",
            "cache-control": "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store",
            "pragma": "no-cache",
            "date": "Thu, 23 May 2024 07:49:22 GMT",
            "connection": "close",
            "x-client-tls-ver": "tls1.3"
        },
        "statusCode": 200
    }
]

I've checked:

The overpayments have line items in Xero.
Using the correct API version and endpoint.
Including the page parameter.

Any ideas on why LineItems are not being returned? Thanks in advance!

Is there an error in your call URL? I see you have Status=="AUTHORISED"&order=Date ASC&page=1 and I wonder if the space in Date ASC is causing the page parameter to be lost. Perhaps either URL-encode it, or surround Date ASC in quotes.
